# Batch-Scripting permission changes for a copied file and subroutine possibilities?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to achieve the following:

For every file in the source folder `%1`; Display it's details, ask the user whether the file should be copied and if the user answers "no" display a message "skipped", otherwise copy the file to the target folder `%2`, set the copy's permissions to "read-only", and display a message.

This is what I have managed so far but the last part I have had no luck understanding.

```
    @echo off

    rem if the source folder does not exist, display a message and exit

    if exist "%1%" (
    echo  .
    ) else (
    echo Source folder doesn't exist.
    exit /b
    )

    if exist "%2%" (
    echo Directory exists
    ) else (
    md %2
    echo Directory Created
    )

    FOR /F "DELIMS==" %%f in ('DIR "%1" /B') DO (

    ECHO %%f
    set p = NULL
    SET /p p="Copy(y/n)?"
    IF "%p%" == "y" (
    COPY "%1\%%f" "%2"
    ECHO Copied %%f to %2
    ) ELSE ( 
    ECHO "%%f" Skipped
    )
    )
```

Is this possible? And if it is can it be done with a subroutine for the iteration process (copying and setting permissions)?

Comment: I have had a look but there seems to be an inherent flaw with the iteration of the copy, the first answer given by the user dictates the operation that is applied to all the files that follow.
e.g. if 'y' entered all following files will be copied even if 'n' is later entered.

Comment: you might have a look at [delayed expansion](http://screwthelotofyou.webs.com/articles/Delayed-expansion.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a batch script to do this operation

```
    @echo off
::This batch file works with arguments or no
::copysec "sourcefolder" "destination folder"

if not "%1" == "" (
 set "source=%1") else (
  set /p "source=Source folder: ")
if not "%2" == "" (
 set "destination=%2") else (
  set /p "destination=Destination folder: ")
if not exist "%destination%" (
 echo/Destination folder %source% not found&pause>nul&exit/b)
if exist "%source%" (
 pushd "%source%") else (
echo/Source folder %source% not found&pause>nul&exit/b)
set /a count=0
for %%f in (*.*) do (
 CALL:PROCESS "%%f")
echo/Finished. %count% files copied
popd&exit/b
:PROCESS file
cls
if "%~x1" == "" (exit/b)
echo/Full path: %~f1&echo/Disk: %~d1
echo/Name: %~n1&echo/Extension: %~x1
echo/Attributes: %~a1&echo/Time %~t1
echo/Size: %~z1 bytes&echo/
set /p "choice=Do you want to copy %1? [Y/N] "
if /i "%choice%" == "y" (
 Goto Y)
 echo/Skipped&timeout 2 1>nul&exit/b
:Y
 copy "%~1" "%destination%\%~1" >nul || GOTO FAIL
 attrib +R "%destination%\%~1" >nul || GOTO FAIL
:NEXT
 set /a count=count+1
 echo/Precess sucefull!&timeout 2 1>nul&exit/b
:FAIL
 echo/Failed to copy %~1
 pause>nul
 exit/b
```

Well if you want to copy all files of all subfolders, you can use for /r
save it as copysec.bat.